# Read property from config server in spring boot 2.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I have below implementation currently working in spring boot 2.3. But when I migrate the same to spring boot 2.4. properties not reading from config server.

**Code**

```
@ConditionalOnProperty({"app.xzy.hosts"})
public class clientConfig { 
 // implementation
}
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
 cloud:
  config:
   uri: http://main-config-server.com
   username: user
   password: pass
   fail-fast: true
```

**application.yml**

```
app:
 xyz:
  hosts: ${app.main.config.hosts}
```

**application.yml in config server**

```
app:
 main:
  config
   hosts: http://myhost.com
```

This implementation is working fine in spring boot 2.3. But after the upgrade to spring boot 2.4 this giving below error in the startup.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'app.xzy.hosts' in value "${app.main.config.hosts}"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
```

Comment: what is the parameters names used to specify config server url

Comment: @MohdAlomar I have updated the question with properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue.

**bootstrap.yml** file is no longer enabled by default. You need enable it by adding new dependency in spring cloud 2020.0.0 and it solved my issue.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Reference: https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/07/spring-cloud-2020-0-0-m4-aka-ilford-is-available